# Is there a way to get all the elements with the same class type

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

Using Appium python client, I want to get all the view returned by;

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(‘foo’)`
in a container; like list or other.

Can I try

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(‘foo’)
for i in len(elements)
   list_element + i = elements
```

Then I can access a list of elements all belonging to the class using list_element?

Comment: Thanks, @frianH, I already did something similar,

```
# Test EditText Class
user_action = TouchAction(driver)
element_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.EditText")

element_class[0].click()
driver.set_value(element_class[0], "Goodies")

# swipe down on new screen
driver.execute_script('mobile: performEditorAction', {'action': 'done'})
```
so is there a way to ```print (elements[i])``` and get the name of elements in each index?  
Also, the code that swipes down doesn't work. I tried to put a delay before calling that.. still nothing, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Let say you want click:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

Or if you want access particular element in `elements`, you can use index:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')
#first element
elements[0].click()
```